# Windows Phone - Change Content Foreground Color when Button Pressed

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

When the following button is pressed, the foreground color of the TextBlock is changed to White (based on the default style of windows phone buttons).  I would like to have the color of the Path to also change to white. 
Is this possible to do with XAML markup?

```
<Button 
    x:Name="MyButton" 
    Foreground="Red" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid Width="175" Height="175">
        <TextBlock 
            x:Name="MyText"
            Text="ABC" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

        <Path
            Fill="MidnightBlue"
            Stretch="Uniform"
            Data="M95.784 59.057c1.867 0 3.604-1.514 3.858-3.364c0 0 0.357-2.6 0.357-5.692c0-3.092-0.357-5.692-0.357-5.692  c-0.255-1.851-1.991-3.364-3.858-3.364h-9.648c-1.868 0-3.808-1.191-4.31-2.646s-1.193-6.123 0.128-7.443l6.82-6.82  c1.32-1.321 1.422-3.575 0.226-5.01L80.976 11c-1.435-1.197-3.688-1.095-5.01 0.226l-6.82 6.82c-1.32 1.321-3.521 1.853-4.888 1.183  c-1.368-0.67-5.201-3.496-5.201-5.364V4.217c0-1.868-1.514-3.604-3.364-3.859c0 0-2.6-0.358-5.692-0.358s-5.692 0.358-5.692 0.358  c-1.851 0.254-3.365 1.991-3.365 3.859v9.648c0 1.868-1.19 3.807-2.646 4.31c-1.456 0.502-6.123 1.193-7.444-0.128l-6.82-6.82  C22.713 9.906 20.459 9.804 19.025 11L11 19.025c-1.197 1.435-1.095 3.689 0.226 5.01l6.819 6.82  c1.321 1.321 1.854 3.521 1.183 4.888s-3.496 5.201-5.364 5.201H4.217c-1.868 0-3.604 1.514-3.859 3.364c0 0-0.358 2.6-0.358 5.692  c0 3.093 0.358 5.692 0.358 5.692c0.254 1.851 1.991 3.364 3.859 3.364h9.648c1.868 0 3.807 1.19 4.309 2.646  c0.502 1.455 1.193 6.122-0.128 7.443l-6.819 6.819c-1.321 1.321-1.423 3.575-0.226 5.01L19.025 89  c1.435 1.196 3.688 1.095 5.009-0.226l6.82-6.82c1.321-1.32 3.521-1.853 4.889-1.183c1.368 0.67 5.201 3.496 5.201 5.364v9.648  c0 1.867 1.514 3.604 3.365 3.858c0 0 2.599 0.357 5.692 0.357s5.692-0.357 5.692-0.357c1.851-0.255 3.364-1.991 3.364-3.858v-9.648  c0-1.868 1.19-3.808 2.646-4.31s6.123-1.192 7.444 0.128l6.819 6.82c1.321 1.32 3.575 1.422 5.01 0.226L89 80.976  c1.196-1.435 1.095-3.688-0.227-5.01l-6.819-6.819c-1.321-1.321-1.854-3.521-1.183-4.889c0.67-1.368 3.496-5.201 5.364-5.201H95.784  z M50 68.302c-10.108 0-18.302-8.193-18.302-18.302c0-10.107 8.194-18.302 18.302-18.302c10.108 0 18.302 8.194 18.302 18.302  C68.302 60.108 60.108 68.302 50 68.302z"
            />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a custom button style like this:

```
   <Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="MyPath">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="MidnightBlue"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="MyPath">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#ffffff"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <Grid Width="175" Height="175" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                <Path x:Name="MyPath"
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                Stretch="Uniform"
                                Data="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then use it:

```
<Button Tag="ABC" Content="M95.784 59.057c1.867 0 3.604-1.514 3.858-3.364c0 0 0.357-2.6 0.357-5.692c0-3.092-0.357-5.692-0.357-5.692  c-0.255-1.851-1.991-3.364-3.858-3.364h-9.648c-1.868 0-3.808-1.191-4.31-2.646s-1.193-6.123 0.128-7.443l6.82-6.82  c1.32-1.321 1.422-3.575 0.226-5.01L80.976 11c-1.435-1.197-3.688-1.095-5.01 0.226l-6.82 6.82c-1.32 1.321-3.521 1.853-4.888 1.183  c-1.368-0.67-5.201-3.496-5.201-5.364V4.217c0-1.868-1.514-3.604-3.364-3.859c0 0-2.6-0.358-5.692-0.358s-5.692 0.358-5.692 0.358  c-1.851 0.254-3.365 1.991-3.365 3.859v9.648c0 1.868-1.19 3.807-2.646 4.31c-1.456 0.502-6.123 1.193-7.444-0.128l-6.82-6.82  C22.713 9.906 20.459 9.804 19.025 11L11 19.025c-1.197 1.435-1.095 3.689 0.226 5.01l6.819 6.82  c1.321 1.321 1.854 3.521 1.183 4.888s-3.496 5.201-5.364 5.201H4.217c-1.868 0-3.604 1.514-3.859 3.364c0 0-0.358 2.6-0.358 5.692  c0 3.093 0.358 5.692 0.358 5.692c0.254 1.851 1.991 3.364 3.859 3.364h9.648c1.868 0 3.807 1.19 4.309 2.646  c0.502 1.455 1.193 6.122-0.128 7.443l-6.819 6.819c-1.321 1.321-1.423 3.575-0.226 5.01L19.025 89  c1.435 1.196 3.688 1.095 5.009-0.226l6.82-6.82c1.321-1.32 3.521-1.853 4.889-1.183c1.368 0.67 5.201 3.496 5.201 5.364v9.648  c0 1.867 1.514 3.604 3.365 3.858c0 0 2.599 0.357 5.692 0.357s5.692-0.357 5.692-0.357c1.851-0.255 3.364-1.991 3.364-3.858v-9.648  c0-1.868 1.19-3.808 2.646-4.31s6.123-1.192 7.444 0.128l6.819 6.82c1.321 1.32 3.575 1.422 5.01 0.226L89 80.976  c1.196-1.435 1.095-3.688-0.227-5.01l-6.819-6.819c-1.321-1.321-1.854-3.521-1.183-4.889c0.67-1.368 3.496-5.201 5.364-5.201H95.784  z M50 68.302c-10.108 0-18.302-8.193-18.302-18.302c0-10.107 8.194-18.302 18.302-18.302c10.108 0 18.302 8.194 18.302 18.302  C68.302 60.108 60.108 68.302 50 68.302z" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" Background="MidnightBlue" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```

UPDATE: Do some trick so that the button can use custom path. Of course, it is also not a generic solution (which must be creating a custom control).

Comment: I have three buttons with three separate paths.  This solution would require a separate style template for each button.  That's a whole lot of xaml.  I am after a solution where you define the style once, and use it for different buttons with different contents.

Comment: @BrianDonovan-Smith I have updated the answer to meet your requirement. Next time please state your requirement more clearly.

Comment: Thanks David, but it is still not resolving the original problem. Microsoft must have solved this for the TextBlock by somehow binding the foreground to the parent content controls foreground color.

Comment: It won't work, because `Path`'s color was brought by `Fill` property, not `Foreground`. The text's color changes only because its `Foreground` inherits value from the `ContentControl`'s `Foreground` which is changed according to the button's `CommonStates`.

Comment: OK. I was hoping there is some kind of {Binding} statement I could use to bind Fill to the ContentsControls Foreground property.

Comment: If that is your original problem, then my answer is IMPOSSIBLE. When it comes to `State` (in this case `Pressed` state), with xaml alone, you can only intercept inside its control template. As I said, `TextBlock` is just an exception. If you want any control behaves like it, then either make sure their color is determined by the `Foreground` property or create your custom button, both of which can't be achieved only by some XAML markup.